# Root access in android

Tags: root-access

How to get root access in android ?. While  I am trying su or sudo in my samsung galaxy core phone ,I am getting /system/bin/sh :sudo :not found

Comment: You have to root your phone. Search (here or on Google) for "How to root <your phone>".

Answer (score 0):

You first have to root your device in order to have root access.
I'd suggest you to have a look [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276).
Do check for supported devices [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/framaroot-supported-devices-t2722980) [as per devices, samsung galaxy core is supported. Do cross-check whether you own the same model or not]

Comment: I haven't done rooting in my device till now.In that case ,do you mean that none of the applications currently running in my mobile phone ,including anti virus is having root access ? What I mean is that, although I haven't done rooting in my mobile phone, how a privileged application like anti virus is running in my mobile ? Or is it running with limited privileges?

Comment: Rooting your device gives YOU administrative rights. 
Means once you root your device, you can explore your device's system files, tweak them, explore all you installed-apps data, install custom ROMs, etc.
All the system files are hidden in UNROOTED device. You do not have permissions to access those files without root.

Comment: If [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device?lq=1) helps you understand more about android root. 
Hope this helps.